# Apps Script to copy data from Google Spreadsheets to Excel File in specific sheet and cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy the data in cells B2:E10 in the sheet "Info" in [this Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1id-tTtfzG_P0XwJJ9Dm0E7CI3KS-m2f9NYymoApfqfw/edit#gid=0) file to cell C5 (until F13) in the sheet "Data" in [this Excel file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zzC0z_RqP1OIUGqxJf07hqds3NjTdOs8/view?usp=sharing) through appscript. It must copy only formats and values since in the original spreadsheet there are formulas.

It is important that the selection range is from B2:E10 and that the pasting is done starting in cell C5.

Is there a simple way to do that with a function on appscript? I want to put that in a button.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to copy the cells "B2:E10" of "Info" sheet in Google Spreadsheet to the cells "C5:F13" of "Data" sheet in Excel file.
- When the values are copied, you want to copy only the display values and cell format.

Unfortunately, in the current stage, the values cannot be directly put to the Excel file using Google Spreadsheet service and Sheets API. So in order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Retrieve range from the source Google Spreadsheet.
2. Convert the destination Excel file to Google Spreadsheet as a temporal Spreadsheet.

   - In this case, the method of "Files: copy" of Drive API is used.
3. Copy the values from source Spreadsheet to destination Spreadsheet.
4. Convert destination Google Spreadsheet to Excel format.
5. Update the destination Excel file.

   - In this case, the method of "Files: update" of Drive API is used.
6. Remove the temporal Google Spreadsheet.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services), and set the variables of `spreadsheetId` and `excelFileId`.

```
function myFunction() {
  const spreadsheetId = "###";  // Please set Spreadsheet ID.
  const excelFileId = "###";  // Please set Excel file ID.

  const sourceRange = "B2:E10";
  const destinationRange = "C5:F13";
  
  // 1. Retrieve range from the source Google Spreadsheet.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Info");
  const range = sheet.getRange(sourceRange);
  const temp = ss.insertSheet();
  const dst = temp.getRange(sourceRange);
  range.copyTo(dst, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT);
  dst.setValues(range.getDisplayValues());
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
  // 2. Convert the destination Excel file to Google Spreadsheet as a temporal Spreadsheet.
  const tempSpreadsheetId = Drive.Files.copy({title: "tempSpreadsheet", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, excelFileId).id;
  
  // 3. Copy the values from source Spreadsheet to destination Spreadsheet.
  const tempSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(tempSpreadsheetId);
  const copiedTemp = temp.copyTo(tempSS);
  const dstSheet = tempSS.getSheetByName("Data");
  const srcRange = copiedTemp.getRange(sourceRange);
  const dstRange = dstSheet.getRange(destinationRange);
  srcRange.copyTo(dstRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT);
  dstRange.setValues(srcRange.getValues());
  ss.deleteSheet(temp);
  tempSS.deleteSheet(copiedTemp);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
  // 4. Convert destination Google Spreadsheet to Excel format.
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?exportFormat=xlsx&id=" + tempSpreadsheetId;
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}).getBlob();
  
  // 5. Update the destination Excel file.
  Drive.Files.update({}, excelFileId, blob);
  
  // 6. Remove the temporal Google Spreadsheet.
  DriveApp.getFileById(tempSpreadsheetId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/copy)
- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update)